# CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH doesn't works

Tags: gcc, include

I have set my environment variable `CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH` to `boost`.

```
>echo $CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH
boost
```

But it doesn't work at all.

```
>g++ parse_utils.cpp
parse_utils.cpp:1:34: fatal error: boost/lexical_cast.hpp: No such file or directory
```

The `.hpp` is in that path.

```
>g++ parse_utils.cpp -Iboost 
(work well)
```

I thought `CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH` is equivalent to `-I` option?

```
>g++ --version
g++ (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5) 4.6.3
```

Comment: Does it work if you use `-Iboost`? I guess you need `-I./boost` instead. The same should be true for the env var.

Comment: why? Isn't it a colon-separated variable? (btw `boost` doesn't work either)

Comment: Did you try `./boost` for the env var?

Comment: Also, did you `export CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH`?

Comment: oh no! I forgot to `export` it! How stupid me...

Comment: it works now. Thank you and you can submit it as an answer so that I can accept it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to export the variable before running g++:

```
export CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH
```

Comment: For smoother experience, add the line `export CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH=/dir/you/want/searched` in your `.bashrc`

Answer (score 0):

In my experience besides setting `CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH` I also had to set the `C_INCLUDE_PATH` variable.